# Edit data with bootstrap modal in PHP

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

now I'm just learning the MVC concept in php native, I'm having trouble when I want to update data with bootstrap modal.
Here's what I'm trying to display my code structure:

button to show modal

```html
<td class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn icon btn-success edit-emp" data-id="<?= $row['id_divisi']; ?>">
</td>
```

My Modal :

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-emp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="<?= base_url; ?>/emp/updateemp" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">
                        Edit Employee
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-3">
                                <label class="col-form-label" for="employee_name">Employee name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-9">
                                <input type="text" id="id_emp" name="id_emp">
                                <input type="text" id="emp_name" class="form-control" name="emp_name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ms-1">
                        save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this my js :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit-dvs").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id")
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + '/emp/edit/' + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#id_emp").val(data.id_emp)
                $("#emp_name").val(data.emp_namei)
                $("#edit-emp").modal("show")
            },
        })
    })
})
```

And This My Emp EmpController And EmpModels :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data = $this->model('EmpModel')->getEmpById($id)->row_array();
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function getEmpById($id)
{
    $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE id_emp=:id_emp');
    $this->db->bind('id_emp', $id);
    return $this->db->single();
}
```

From what I have tried above, I still haven't succeeded in being able to display the modal along with the sent id_emp data. I hope someone can kindly tell me to improve my code. Thank you.

Comment: Please translate your last sentence in English

Comment: sorry, I've fixed it now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test with your code.
The first problem I've found is that you are listening to the *onclick* with a wrong selector, you have:

```js
 $(".edit-dvs").on("click", function() {
```

but your button doesn't have that class:

```php
<button type="button" class="btn icon btn-success edit-emp" data-id="<?= $row['id_divisi']; ?>">
```

Fixing that, the modal starts working.

The second problem is that in your form you have omitted the *$* character in the *$base_url* variable, you have:

```
<form action="<?= base_url; ?>/emp/updateemp" method="POST">
```